# openLDAP samples

Tags: ldap

I want to explore openLDAP.. Can any one suggest me some websites for simple ldap codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options if you are looking for java libraries

- [JNDI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/TOC.html)
- [JLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/jldap/)
- [Examples using jldap](http://developer.novell.com/documentation/samplecode/jldap_sample/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explore what is LDAP.You can go for 389 Directory Server(Open LDAP )
Refer below link.Install it.It has GUI for administration.

> http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Main_Page

For JNDI ,to call you can refer below site and code below to connect LDAP server

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/models/operations.html

```
                Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
                env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, UserContextBean.getEntrydn());
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, authenticationType);
                LDAPContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
```

This ctx can be use to access directory.